# Is there an excel command to add subsets of each column?

Tags: excel

I have a column full of numbers in the following format:

```
1
2
3

5
6
7
8

4
9

10
```

I would like to be able to add each subset of numbers and display that sum to the column to the right like so:

```
1    
2
3    6

5
6
7
8    26

4
9    13

10   10
```

Is there a way to do this with an excel command?

Comment: Is a blank row separating your subsets? If not, is there some delimiter?

Comment: Yeah, each subset is separated by a blank row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1:A10`, you could do something like the following in `B2`:

```
=IF(A3="", SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1), "")
```

Then copy down to the end of your data.

This tests if the next row is blank, if so it sums up everything above it and subtracts the sums that we've already calculated for previous sets.

Comment: I was going a totally different way that was getting to complicated the further I went.  This is supper simple.

Comment: I thought, for certain, that this was going to go that way too, but then I pulled that `-sum($B$1:B1)` out of the blue and it worked out. I'm convinced there is a better way to do this with `subtotal()`, but I don't use that enough to try.

Comment: Yeah that `-Sum($B$1:B1)` is pretty sharp, nice thinking.